# Django Admin. How to Change position of field labels

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I need to work with Persian language. Persian is right aligned so I want the labels of model fields to appear on the right side of the input box.

I tried to change the admin page CSS but it didn't work.(I changed `text-aligned` to `right-aligned`).

Comment: You want your text to be in reverse or just the input to be aligned on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

Could try adding this to the css:

```
.form-row div {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

You could also use `direction: rtl` instead of `flex-direction: row-reverse` This works because the structure of the generated html will be something like:

```
<div class="form-row>
    <div>
        <label ...>
        <input ...>
    </div>
</div>
```

Depending on how complicated the layout it, this might not work 100%, I've not looked at how it will affect inlines and other ways you can lay things out in the django-admin, but some variation of it should fix your basic problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the code you suggested but I change `direction: row-reverse;`  to `direction: rtl;` and It worked!

Comment: Ah, my bad. That should have said `flex-direction: row-reverse`. But yes, `direction: rtl` works just as well. I'll update my answer. If you're happy with it as the correct answer please give it an upvote, and tick to accept it as correct.

Comment: @behnam.m if you're happy with this answer, could you accept it and upvote it. Thanks :)